# Can't connect to Mysql from 3.x or above with my Android emulators

Tags: java, android, mysql, eclipse, emulation

I'm using Eclipse and I'm tryin' to charge some data from a Database in a local network.
The problem is that when I use an emulator with 2.x the program can retrieve the information that I need without problems but when I try to run the program into an emulator with 3.x or
4.x Android it can't retrieve the information.

I'm using a MySQL database in my local network, not in the localhost.

This is the code I'm using to connect:

```
public static void CreaConexion (Context context, String usuario, String pass, String ip, String puerto, String catalogo)
{
    if (conexionMySQL == null)      
    {
        String urlConexionMySQL = "";

        if (catalogo != "")
            urlConexionMySQL = "jdbc:mysql://" + ip + ":" + puerto + "/" + catalogo;
        else
            urlConexionMySQL = "jdbc:mysql://" + ip + ":" + puerto;

        if (usuario != "" & pass != "" & ip != "" & puerto != "")
        {
            try 
            {
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

                Toast.makeText(context, urlConexionMySQL, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                conexionMySQL = DriverManager.getConnection(urlConexionMySQL, usuario, pass);
            } 
            catch (ClassNotFoundException e) 
            {
                  Toast.makeText(context, "Error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } 
            catch (SQLException e) 
            {
                  Toast.makeText(context, "Error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm getting:
    Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

This is my first post and I don't speak english as native but I hope you can understand me =). Thanks!

Comment: post the complete exception. do you have some kind of firewall or anything blocking connection to the server?

Comment: Unafortunately I can't post the complete error until the Monday. But I know that I've deactivated the firewall.